# Converting WP_User_Query to SQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to convert WP_User_Query to SQL query.

This is the original User Query:

```
// $roles is an array of user roles and may vary based on user input 
// E.g.: $roles = array('editor', 'author');


$args_users = array(
    'role__in' => $roles,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(    
            'key'   => 'my_meta_key',
            'value' => 'my_meta_value',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'count_total' => true
);

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args_users );
$users_count = $users->get_total();

echo $users_count; // Returns 15.
```

And this is what I tried so far, with no luck:

```
$placeholders = implode( ', ', array_fill( 0, count( $roles ), '%s' ) );

$users_count = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS um1 ON $wpdb->users.ID = um1.user_id
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS um2 ON $wpdb->users.ID = um2.user_id
        WHERE  um1.meta_key = 'my_meta_key' AND um1.meta_value = 'my_meta_value'
        AND um2.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND um2.meta_value IN ($placeholders)",
        $roles
    )
); 

echo $users_count; // Returns 0. Should return 15.
```

Both should return 15, but the SQL query returns 0.